# How to avoid duplicate pre-build events and copy assemblies of the referenced project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a Visual Studio 2013 project named B and it has a pre-build event that copies and unmanaged 3rd party assembly into its $(TargetDir). The project then is referenced by another project named A (A creates a project reference to B). When I build my project B, I get the unmanaged 3rd party dll copied to the project's $(TargetDir) location. However, when I build my project A or the whole solution which contains both projects, I do not get the 3rd party dll in the project A's $(TargetDir).

What do I do to get the 3rd party dll to automatically copy in the project A's $(TargetDir) without having to write another (duplicate) pre-build event

Comment: I think you can write your custom build task in an external file, and then you can reference it from each of your projects build files (csproj).